# Error: multiple types matching the name while Scaffolding ASP.NET Core MVC RC2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm developing a web app in Asp.Net Core RC2 according to n-layered architecture.

[image]

When I try to use scaffolding to generate CRUD Controller and Views, I get the following error.

[image]

I have separated my Models/ViewModels and Context/Repository Classes into Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer respectively. I'm referencing both these layers in OpenBiz project as nuget packages. But cannot perform scaffolding as seen above. Is there an issue with my architecture or am I missing something here?

Comment: Any help? Also asked this on Github repo of Scaffolding.

Comment: I've even re created the project but all in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response from [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/249):

> currently there is an issue with scaffolding, that it doesn't support
>   model classes outside of the current project properly.
>
> As a workaround, you can add the model temporarily to your web project
>   and then move it to the BLL/ DAL projects after scaffolding.

Plus they also opened [this issue as a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/251), quoting:

> Scaffolding fails if model class is in a dependency (project/ library)
>   of the project on which scaffolding is being run. #251
>
> Project A has a dependeny on Project B.  Project B has model class  If
>   you try to run scaffolding on Project A by using model class from
>   Project B, it fails with the below error:  No model type returned for
>   type:

Hence, as of RC2, this is a bug in scaffolding tooling.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same bug working with Visual Studio for Mac (v. 17.5.3, build 15) on .Net Core 7.x.y.

The goal was to scaffold Razor Pages Views from an Entity (News), managed by Entity Framework within a DbContext.

I worked it out executing the process by aspnet-codegenerator command line tool:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator razorpage --model MyCompany.Model.News --dataContext DataContext  --referenceScriptLibraries  --useDefaultLayout --no-build -outDir "/Users/dude/Projects/MyCompany/Areas/Identity/Pages/News" --namespaceName MyCompany.Areas.Identity.Pages.NewsBoard
```

For additional informations about this tool, here the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-7.0